# How do you write a matrix using a "for" loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

So for data evaluation that I am doing at the moment I want to write a matrix using a "for" loop.

Let's say I have random numbers between 0 and 100:

```
E <- runif(100, 0, 100)

t <- 0 #start

for(t in 0:90) {
   D <- length(E[E >= t, E < (t + 10)])
   t = t + 10
}
```

So what I want to do is write "D" into a matrix at each iteration with "t" in one column and "D" in the other.

I've heard that you should avoid loops in R, but I don't know an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a loop, you can do this with `sapply`, which operates on each item in a sequence and stores the result in a vector, and then `cbind` to create the matrix:

```r
E <- runif(100, 0, 100)
t <- seq(0, 90, 10)

D <- sapply(t, function(ti) {
  sum(E >= ti & E < (ti + 10))
})

cbind(t, D)
#>        t  D
#>  [1,]  0 11
#>  [2,] 10 12
#>  [3,] 20 14
#>  [4,] 30 11
#>  [5,] 40  9
#>  [6,] 50 12
#>  [7,] 60  7
#>  [8,] 70  7
#>  [9,] 80  6
#> [10,] 90 11
```

Note that I also used `sum(E >= ti & E < (ti + 10))` rather than `length(length(E[E >= ti & E < (ti + 10)]))`, as a slightly shorter way of finding the number of items in `E` that were greater than `t` but less than `t + 10`.

Comment: @Tarkus you're welcome. Note that for this *particular* application, you also have the option of `cbind(t, table(findInterval(E, t)))`, since `findInterval` does what you're looking for in terms of binning items and `table` counts the values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to bin your variable into categories - this is exactly what [cut](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.0.3/topics/cut) does:

```
E <- runif(100, 0, 100)
table(cut(E, breaks = seq(0,100,10), right=FALSE))

#>  [0,10)  [10,20)  [20,30)  [30,40)  [40,50)  [50,60)  [60,70)  [70,80)  [80,90) 
#>      10       10        7       10        8       10       12       11       10 
#>[90,100) 
#>      12
```

If you don't want to see categories labels, remove `table` call; if you want it in "tabular" format, wrap it in `as.matrix`.

Please note that if you are doing it for plotting purposes, then both `hist` and `ggplot` will do it automatically for you:

```
hist(E, breaks = seq(0,100,10))
```

[image: hist output]

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data.frame(var=E), aes(x=var)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)
```

[image: ggplot output]